# Vaadin 14 File downloading on Button Click not works

Tags: vaadin

I am using https://vaadin.com/directory/component/file-download-wrapper
with below code

```
 exportButton = new Button("export"));

 FileDownloadWrapper buttonWrapper = new FileDownloadWrapper(
            new StreamResource(genericGridView.getExportFileCaption(), () -> getExportStream()));

 buttonWrapper.wrapComponent(exportButton);

 buttonLayout.add(exportButton); //Button Layout is an Horizontal Layout which is added finally in the 
                                   main Layout.
```

and this part of code is written at the loading time of my view. But the method getExportStream method not getting executed(Tried to Put debug in eclipse but it never executed) neither on view load nor in button click event.

Please can you help in this implementation, whether I am doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the code using `FileDownloadWrapper` looks correct. So I tend to think that the problem is more related to how you generate the data. I copy here one code snippet from my test apps that works. The CSV export here uses `StatefulBeanToCsv` and `StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder` from `com.opencsv.opencsv` library.

```
private void export(Grid<Person> grid, TextArea result) {
    Set<Person> selection = grid.asMultiSelect().getValue();
    Stream<Person> persons = persons = selection.stream();

    StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
    StatefulBeanToCsv<Person> writer = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<Person>(
            output).build();
    try {
        writer.write(persons);
    } catch (CsvDataTypeMismatchException
            | CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException e) {
        output.write("An error occured during writing: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    result.setValue(output.toString());
    StreamResource resource = new StreamResource("export.csv",
            () -> new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toString().getBytes()));
    FileDownloadWrapper download = new FileDownloadWrapper(resource);

    Button button = new Button("Click to download");
    download.wrapComponent(button);
    add(download);
}
```

Comment: Okay I found the problem, I was adding my button to the layout when I added the ButtonWrapper its worked.

add(download); // This download for me was the button object instead of 
                              FileDownloadWrapper .

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the FileDownloadWrapper to the layout instead of the Button. Otherwise, the FileDownloadWrapper does nothing.

Comment: Had the same issue and this hint solved it for me. Thank you!